# Triggering jQuery on resize and current window size?

Tags: jquery, resize, responsive

With this Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/Aurk8/

The event happens when the window is resized, but what I'd like to happen is that, if the window is already at said size, then it should run the  code, at the moment, the window listens for a resize trigger, but doesn't work if you refresh the page at the resized width.

Effectively, I want to turn an list into a select menu if the screen size is below 992 px width, I thought I could do this by checking the window size... if it's at 992 pixels, then add a class...then that class runs the magic that turns the list into an item... For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
jQuery(window).on('resize', function(event){
var windowSize = jQuery(window).width();
if(windowSize < 992){
    jQuery( "ul#intro-tabs" ).addClass( "tabs-select" );
} else {
    jQuery( "ul#intro-tabs" ).removeClass( "tabs-select" );
}
});

// Turn a list in to an select menu   

jQuery('ul.tabs-select').each(function(){
var list=jQuery(this),
    select=jQuery(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore(jQuery(this)
.hide()).change(function(){
  window.location.href=jQuery(this).val();
});
jQuery('>li a', this).each(function(){
  var option=jQuery(document.createElement('option'))
   .appendTo(select)
   .val(this.href)
   .html(jQuery(this).html());
  if(jQuery(this).attr('class') === 'selected'){
    option.attr('selected','selected');
  }
});
list.remove();
});

});
```

Comment: Add a jQuery(window).trigger("resize") at the botom of your document.ready function then.
This will trigger the resize event when the window first loads, that will cause your function to run and check everything without waiting for the user to resize.

Comment: Looks good to me, yes thats worked. Thank you.